# How to write a java script for specific Test attempts

Tags: javascript, articulate-storyline

I am having a java scripts for a game, but this game is like a test and if the user failed the game he will retake the test (redo the game), but I want a specific number of attempts only for the user to re do the test. now what I have, makes the user start from the beginning without any limitations even if he re do it for like 100 times, he will keep go back to the beginning.

I need in the fail massage to give another attempt (form like max 4 attempts) if failed once then the next fail massage to give him 3  tries and then 2 and then last one, and then he can't redo the test.

Script 1;

```
var player=GetPlayer();

var textArray = [];


for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    textArray.push(i); 

};


var itemsLeft = textArray.length;

textArray=textArray.map(String).toString();
player.SetVar("Text_Array", textArray);

player.SetVar("Items_Left", itemsLeft);
```

Script 2:

```
//get the StoryLine player
var player=GetPlayer();

//get Storyline variable value as a string
var textArray=player.GetVar("Text_Array");

//Convert string to a numeric array
numArray=textArray.split(",").map(Number);

//Get a random number from the array and send it to StoryLine
var randNum = numArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numArray.length)];
player.SetVar("Random",randNum);

//Remove the random number from your array and get the array's length
numArray.splice(numArray.indexOf(randNum), 1);
var itemsLeft=numArray.length;

//Convert array to a string and send it back to SL along with the array's length
textArray=numArray.map(String).toString();
player.SetVar("Items_Left", itemsLeft);
player.SetVar("Text_Array", textArray);
```